# "expected package `<PACKAGE_NAME> [99a43ef4]` to be registered" in CI workflow

Tags: github, julia, documentation

I want to have an exercise in deploying documentation of a tiny personal julia package using GitHub pages. You can check out the repo [here](https://github.com/shayandavoodii/MFF). I have an empty branch named `gh-pages` to commit the doc-related content into it after each release or push. For this, I used a [pre-written script](https://github.com/m3g/JuliaNotes.jl/blob/main/.github/workflows/ci.yml) for the CI workflow. However, still I cant deploy the docs successfully due to this error:

```
ERROR: expected package `MFF [99a43ef4]` to be registered
```

I don't intend to register the package and it's for my personal use. How can I deploy the documentation via GitHub pages?

## Further information

Note that I tried to follow several tutorials:

1. The one that has been provided in [Documenter.jl](https://documenter.juliadocs.org/stable/man/guide/)
2. "How to deploy the documentation of a project" from [JuliaNotes.jl](https://m3g.github.io/JuliaNotes.jl/stable/publish_docs/#How-to-deploy-the-documentation-of-a-project)

Considering the proposed procedures and the outcome of my attempt, I don't find the topic straightforward. So a concise step-by-step procedure would be helpful.

Q1: What do you mean by *"step-by-step"*?
A: For example, in the ["Use DocumenterTools to generate the keys"](https://m3g.github.io/JuliaNotes.jl/stable/publish_docs/#Use-DocumenterTools-to-generate-the-keys) (or similarly, in Documenter.jl [relevant doc](https://documenter.juliadocs.org/stable/man/hosting/#travis-ssh)) topic, they mentioned that one can use `DocumenterTools.genkeys()` to generate public and private keys, but they didn't mention that is it important to run the command in a specific Julia env (like the one in the `/docs` dir) or not.

The full error of CI workflow is as follows (originally can be found [here](https://github.com/shayandavoodii/MFF/actions/runs/4504729235/jobs/7929577894) as well)

```
Run julia --project=docs -e '
  Installing known registries into `~/.julia`
    Updating registry at `~/.julia/registries/General.toml`
   Resolving package versions...
ERROR: expected package `MFF [99a43ef4]` to be registered
Stacktrace:
  [1] pkgerror(msg::String)
    @ Pkg.Types /opt/hostedtoolcache/julia/1.8.5/x64/share/julia/stdlib/v1.8/Pkg/src/Types.jl:67
  [2] check_registered
    @ /opt/hostedtoolcache/julia/1.8.5/x64/share/julia/stdlib/v1.8/Pkg/src/Operations.jl:1190 [inlined]
  [3] targeted_resolve(env::Pkg.Types.EnvCache, registries::Vector{Pkg.Registry.RegistryInstance}, pkgs::Vector{Pkg.Types.PackageSpec}, preserve::Pkg.Types.PreserveLevel, julia_version::VersionNumber)
    @ Pkg.Operations /opt/hostedtoolcache/julia/1.8.5/x64/share/julia/stdlib/v1.8/Pkg/src/Operations.jl:1252
  [4] tiered_resolve(env::Pkg.Types.EnvCache, registries::Vector{Pkg.Registry.RegistryInstance}, pkgs::Vector{Pkg.Types.PackageSpec}, julia_version::VersionNumber)
    @ Pkg.Operations /opt/hostedtoolcache/julia/1.8.5/x64/share/julia/stdlib/v1.8/Pkg/src/Operations.jl:1225
  [5] _resolve(io::Base.PipeEndpoint, env::Pkg.Types.EnvCache, registries::Vector{Pkg.Registry.RegistryInstance}, pkgs::Vector{Pkg.Types.PackageSpec}, preserve::Pkg.Types.PreserveLevel, julia_version::VersionNumber)
    @ Pkg.Operations /opt/hostedtoolcache/julia/1.8.5/x64/share/julia/stdlib/v1.8/Pkg/src/Operations.jl:1260
  [6] add(ctx::Pkg.Types.Context, pkgs::Vector{Pkg.Types.PackageSpec}, new_git::Set{Base.UUID}; preserve::Pkg.Types.PreserveLevel, platform::Base.BinaryPlatforms.Platform)
    @ Pkg.Operations /opt/hostedtoolcache/julia/1.8.5/x64/share/julia/stdlib/v1.8/Pkg/src/Operations.jl:1276
  [7] add(ctx::Pkg.Types.Context, pkgs::Vector{Pkg.Types.PackageSpec}; preserve::Pkg.Types.PreserveLevel, platform::Base.BinaryPlatforms.Platform, kwargs::Base.Pairs{Symbol, Base.PipeEndpoint, Tuple{Symbol}, NamedTuple{(:io,), Tuple{Base.PipeEndpoint}}})
    @ Pkg.API /opt/hostedtoolcache/julia/1.8.5/x64/share/julia/stdlib/v1.8/Pkg/src/API.jl:275
  [8] add(pkgs::Vector{Pkg.Types.PackageSpec}; io::Base.PipeEndpoint, kwargs::Base.Pairs{Symbol, Union{}, Tuple{}, NamedTuple{(), Tuple{}}})
    @ Pkg.API /opt/hostedtoolcache/julia/1.8.5/x64/share/julia/stdlib/v1.8/Pkg/src/API.jl:156
  [9] add(pkgs::Vector{Pkg.Types.PackageSpec})
    @ Pkg.API /opt/hostedtoolcache/julia/1.8.5/x64/share/julia/stdlib/v1.8/Pkg/src/API.jl:145
 [10] #add#27
    @ /opt/hostedtoolcache/julia/1.8.5/x64/share/julia/stdlib/v1.8/Pkg/src/API.jl:144 [inlined]
 [11] add
    @ /opt/hostedtoolcache/julia/1.8.5/x64/share/julia/stdlib/v1.8/Pkg/src/API.jl:144 [inlined]
 [12] #add#26
    @ /opt/hostedtoolcache/julia/1.8.5/x64/share/julia/stdlib/v1.8/Pkg/src/API.jl:143 [inlined]
 [13] add(pkg::String)
    @ Pkg.API /opt/hostedtoolcache/julia/1.8.5/x64/share/julia/stdlib/v1.8/Pkg/src/API.jl:143
 [14] top-level scope
    @ none:2
Error: Process completed with exit code 1.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hey I noticed two things. First you dont have a Documenter.yml file in your github workflows.

But I am also thinking Julia can simply not find your package when it runs the

```
using MFF
```

line in your make.jl file (in the docs folder).

Just comparing it to my own package where documentation works I would think maybe adding

```
push!(LOAD_PATH,"../src/")
using Documenter
using MFF
```

to your make.jl file in the docs folder would enable julia to find the MFF package that you are loading.

Hope this solves your problem.

Edit: Also just saw that you include the MFF package in the project.toml in the docs folder. I think you need to get rid of that one and just keep the Documenter entry in there.

Comment: Thank you for your help. Although the error is gone after following your advice, I get "error 404 File not found" when I try to load the doc: https://shayandavoodii.github.io/MFF/

Comment: Thank you! By following your hint and [the help of Mr. Giordano](https://julialang.slack.com/archives/C67910KEH/p1679693485139299?thread_ts=1679692672.849829&cid=C67910KEH), the problem got solved.